# Search Php array for string and extract adjacent text

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to generate a table with name, email and phone number from a mysql database.  I am using php to create the table and I have most of it figured out except how to get a person's phone number if present.  This is tricky because unlike name and email there is no special field for the information if present (not everyone gave a phone number).  If the phone number is present it is contained in a "params" field with a bunch of other data.  My code generates the table using this statement:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

In order to show what the data looks like that I need to sift through I executed a "print_r command the result of which is:

> `Array ( [0] => Manager [usertype] => Manager [1] => 167 [id] => 167 [2] => Sam Spade [Name] => Sam Spade [3] => sm@aol.com [Email] => sm@aol.com [4] => 167 [user_id] => 167 [5] => {"birth_year":"1911","ride_note":"on","membership_visible":"on","volunteer":["","House Events","House Socials"],"ride_catagory":["10-12","13-15"],"phone":"540-123-4567"} [params] => {"birth_year":"1911","ride_note":"on","membership_visible":"on","volunteer":["","House Events","House Socials"],"ride_catagory":["10-12","13-15"],"phone":"540-123-4567"} )`

How do I extract the phone number 540-123-4567? (If no phone number was given then the word "phone" would not be present as well.)

Thanks

I think we are getting close.  Let me expose more of the code I have so far:

```
$sql = 'SELECT  c.usertype, c.id, c.`name` as Name, c.`email` as Email, j.user_id, j.`params`  
                FROM j25_akeebasubs_users j, j25_users c WHERE j.params LIKE "%membership_visible%"
                and c.id = j.user_id and usertype != "Registered" order by c.name;';

        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());


        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

            $arr = "{$arr}\n
                    <table border=1 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=2>
                    <col width=200px />
                    <col width=300px />
                    <col width=150px />
                    <tr>
                        <td>{$row['Name']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['Email']}</td>
                        <td>{$row[5]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    \n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n";
        }

            return ($arr);
        }
```

Name and email are working okay.  For the last element, $row[5], I naturally get all the data present from which I just need the phone number.

Comment: that looks like JSON strings. quick/dirty search would be to look for `"phone":`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Marc B is right and it's valid JSON in your params field, you should be able to do something like this:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

   $user_params = json_decode($row['params'], true);


        $arr = "{$arr}\n
                <table border=1 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=2>
                <col width=200px />
                <col width=300px />
                <col width=150px />
                <tr>
                    <td>{$row['Name']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['Email']}</td>
                    <td>{$user_params['phone']}</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                \n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n";

}

return $arr;
```

See the PHP Doc for [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

It's a json string, use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode it to array and then you can check if phone variable [isset](http://www.php.net/isset) and access it like in normal array.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: based on the additional code you posted, the row is an array returned from mysql, but the params field is json. Code below is updated:

Seems like you have an array you can just look up stuff from. I'm not sure what code came before. If it's' already an array great, if not use json_decode() to turn string into an array. Then:

```
function getPhone($row) {
    $params = json_decode($row[5], true);
    return $params["phone"];
}
```

I might point out that **mysql is deprecated** and you should be using mysqli (or PDO). Also, the hard-coded array index [5] will get you in trouble if your query changes, so good practice is to get an associative array back and name the fields instead of numbering them. See https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc.

Comment: I think we might be getting close here.  Let me expose more of the code:

Comment: Found part of your print output confusing, but I think the entire 5th element of each row is one big JSOB blob ready to decode.